# Implementing OLAP on titan/cassandra graph

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, titan, tinkerpop3

I am using Titan 1.0.0 on top cassandra. I want to use OLAP services using SparkGraphComputer on the titan/cassandra graph. I have two questions

1) How to do it?

config:
https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/titan10/titan-dist/src/assembly/static/conf/hadoop-graph/read-cassandra.properties

gremlin-code:

```
graph = GraphFactory.open('conf/hadoop-graph/read-cassandra.properties')
g = graph.traversal(computer(SparkGraphComputer))
g.V().count() //Here is the error
```

Error:

```
11:20:33 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor  - Exception in task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
java.lang.RuntimeException: error communicating via Thrift
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader$RowIterator.<init>(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:267)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader$RowIterator.<init>(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:215)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader$StaticRowIterator.<init>(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:331)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader$StaticRowIterator.<init>(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:331)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader.initialize(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:171)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.formats.cassandra.CassandraBinaryRecordReader.initialize(CassandraBinaryRecordReader.java:39)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.hadoop.formats.util.GiraphRecordReader.initialize(GiraphRecordReader.java:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(NewHadoopRDD.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the full trace :
http://pastebin.com/CiuXjFB2

2) Why convert to hadoopGraph when the data is already stored on titan/cassandra?
references:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/fVijONCxvSI

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? Local, standalone cluster, or yarn for the Spark master? Are you building `titan10` or `titan11` from source or using a `titan-1.0.0-hadoop.zip`?

Comment: I am using `titan-1.0.0-hadoop.zip`. Do I need to use Spark saperately? Doesnt it come bundled in Titan?

Comment: You can use Spark in `local` mode, but that likely only adequate for small graphs. What is the actual Gremlin query that you ran against the traversal object `g`? You didn't make any changes in `read-cassandra.properties`?

Comment: `HadoopGraph` allows the OLAP traversal to be distributed to worker processes, potentially on different JVMs. Ultimately it uses the the same data stored in Cassandra -- see the `CassandraInputFormat` and configuration in `read-cassandra.properties`. http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#_olap_hadoop_gremlin

Comment: @JasonPlurad I ran `g.V().count()` against g. Also I tried changing `titanmr.ioformat.conf.storage.backend=cassandra` to `titanmr.ioformat.conf.storage.backend=cassandrathrift` but the error was still there

Comment: @JasonPlurad `HadoopGraph allows the OLAP traversal to be distributed to worker processes, potentially on different JVMs.` Can you explain that?